# override useState variable when it is used in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

my issue is  how to reset a useState variable once I set it in useEffect(). This is my code:

```
    const [warningDay, setWarningDay] = useState('');
    const [warningMonth, setWarningMonth] = useState('');
    const [warningYear, setWarningYear] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
    if (errMsg) {
      setWarningDay('date-dropdown__warning');
      setWarningMonth('date-dropdown__warning');
      setWarningYear('date-dropdown__warning');
    } else {
      setWarningDay('');
      setWarningMonth('');
      setWarningYear('');
    }
  });
```

and inside the component, I have a html select tag that has an onChange function like this:

```
<select
              id={`${props.id}-day`}
              disabled={props.disabled}
              className={classNames('date-dropdown__field', warningDay)}
              onChange={e => {
                setWarningDay('');
              }}
            >
```

Is there a way to setWarningDay() to empty because it always returns to whatever inside the useEffect(). I want to set it empty when users make a change instantly. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that you are missing your dependencies declaration in `useEffect()`. This causes it to run *every time* you render the component. Check the [useEffect()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) docs for more details.

In this case, you are depending on the value of `errMsg`, so it would be a great candidate for this dependencies array.
With this change, the effect will now run *only* when there is change in the `errMsg` variable:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    if (errMsg) {
      setWarningDay('date-dropdown__warning');
      setWarningMonth('date-dropdown__warning');
      setWarningYear('date-dropdown__warning');
    } else {
      setWarningDay('');
      setWarningMonth('');
      setWarningYear('');
    }
  }, [errMsg]); // <- notice the dependencies array added here
```

This should fix your issue, because now you are able to call `setWarningDay()` in other parts of your logic and it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
  // ...
}, [warningDay, warningMonth, warningYear])
```

Can you try this code?